# How to distort a part of a raster image like you do with a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, shapes, raster, distort

As an example I have a raster image as shown:

[image: Figure A]

I want to crop a specific part of that image :

[image: Figure B]

And distort it by its corner points like this :

[image: Figure C]

Can someone please explain to me how to do that using AI and/or PS?
Thank you beforehand.

*Note : You might not see the images embedded if you're viewing this on the app.*

Image Source: https://www.behance.net/gallery/12229929/Digitaland

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with any softwares outside from those two. Thankfully the question has been answered. Though, thank you so much for your time and attention on this; pretty much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for Photoshop.

To begin with, you'd really need an undistorted copy of the letterhead.  Trying to edit an already distorted image is less than ideal because it will degrade the image quality quite a bit. However it could be done. You could try to use the Perspective Crop tool to undistort it first.

The example below shows use of the Perspective Crop tool (circled in red). The inset shows the result. I had to use the Perspective crop tool a couple of times to remove all the distortion.

[image]

Assuming you already have an undistorted copy of the letterhead to work with, an effective method to do something like that in Photoshop would be to turn the letterhead into a Smart Object, which you could then distort using using *Edit > Transform > Distort*.  The Smart Object would effectively behave as a shape which could be transformed non-destructively. The tranform applied to the Smart Object will be remembered and editable at a later point. Also the Smart Object itself will remain editable - double clicking opens the Smart Object for editing.

The example below shows converting an image to a Smart Object, applying a Distort Transform, double clicking the Smart Object to open it, closing the Smart Object, then re-editing the transform.

[image]

Comment: You nailed every point of my question, Billy. Thank you so much, this is really helpful :)

Comment: @Chen Thanks. It might be useful to also consider that you can actually use an AI document as a Smart Object in Photoshop. So if your letterhead was done in Illustrator, you can drag and drop the AI file directly into Photoshop, where it will automatically become a Smart Object, which can be distorted in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in PS:

Assuming you already selected the particular area using pen tool.

- To transform a selected area. Then choose CTRL+T or Edit > Free Transform or Select > Transform Selection
- Select any corner point and hold CTRL and move as you need.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is how to transform part of an image in a particular way as clearly shown by the OP in the example images.

Comment: I Appreciate your answer.. it's just two steps to achieve desired output -as simple as that!

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for answering :) But as Billy said it doesn't really answer my question as I want the image to sort of attached to the path (drawn by pen tool, let's asume). The steps you told me only changes the shape of the path and not the picture outlined by it. Though, thank you again.